# Creating unique constraint to be validated from input

Tags: postgresql, index, postgresql-9.2, unique-constraint

I have this table name `tbl` with this table definition:

```
create table tbl (
    id serial primary key not null,
    counter integer not null default 1,
    ref_id integer not null,
    date_booked date not null
);
```

With these insert statement(s):

```
insert into tbl(counter, ref_id, date_booked) values (1, 1, '2014-07-05');
insert into tbl(counter, ref_id, date_booked) values (2, 2, '2014-07-10');
insert into tbl(counter, ref_id, date_booked) values (3, 3, '2014-07-15');
-- this should fail
insert into tbl(counter, ref_id, date_booked) values (3, 4, '2014-07-20');
```

I am having a problem of creating a unique constraint/index in such way `tbl.counter` should be unique within the month of the inputted `tbl.date_booked`. From the insert statements above, the 4th insert statement should fail since if violates the unique validation. The problem is I don't know how to create such validation. Though I have a bit of an idea about constraints, index, etc. it's just am confused which to choose to make this work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be achieved by using a unique index on the combination of counter and the month of date_booked. Something like this:

```
create unique index idx_tbl on tbl (counter, to_char(date_booked, 'yyyymm'));
```

However the above will fail because `to_char()` is not an "immutable" function and thus cannot be used in an index (even if we *know* that the above is fine). The workaround for this is to create a wrapper function that is marked as immutable:

```
create function my_month(some_date date)
  returns varchar
  immutable 
  language sql
as  
$$
  select to_char(some_date, 'yyyymm')
$$
;
```

Then you can create an index using that function:

```
create unique index idx_tbl on tbl (counter, my_month(date_booked));
```

If you now insert the fourth row, you get the error:

```
duplicate key value violates unique constraint "idx_tbl"
```

If the table is big, you might want to use a number instead of a `varchar` in order to reduce the size of the index as well e.g. by using `to_number(to_char(some_date, 'yyyymm'))`

Comment: Thanks. Can I ask why we need to create a function so serve as a wrapper to make `date_booked` formatted as `yyyymm` immutable?

Comment: @NanoJava Because `to_char()` is **not** marked as immutable (that's why you can't use it in an index definition) and you can not change a built-in function.

Comment: @NanoJava `to_char()` is not immutable, because it can depend on the current locale, f.ex. *`mon`: abbreviated lower case month name (3 chars in English, localized lengths vary)*